# Prove every element of $F(c)$ can be written uniquely as $a_0+a_1c+...+a_{n-}c^{n-1}$ for some $a_0,...,a_{n-1}\in F$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree n in $F[x]$ then $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle \cong F(c)$ where c is a root of $p(x)$. Prove every element of $F(c)$ can be written uniquely as $a_0+a_1c+...+a_{n-}c^{n-1}$ for some $a_0,...,a_{n-1}\in F$.

So to be unique there is only one solution. So I would take $c$ and let $x=c$ then $F(c)/p(c)$ would give us $a_0+a_1c+...+a_{n-}c^{n-1}$ for some $a_0,...,a_{n-1}\in F$, I believe. Is this the correct thinking?

Comment: It looks better to use `\langle p(x) \rangle` $\langle p(x) \rangle$ than `<p(x)>` $<p(x)>$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that $F(c)$ is an $n$ dimensional vector space over $F$ with $\{1,c,c^2,...,c^{n-1}\} $ as a basis. So by basic linear algebra every element in $F(c)$ can be expressed uniquely as a linear combination of the basis elements.

Answer (score 0):

So if $q(x)\in F[x]$ we can use the division algorithm to write $$q(x)=p(x)d(x)+r(x)$$ where the degree of $r$ is strictly less than the degree of $p$.

Now we have $q(c)=r(c)$ as required (existence). If $q(c)=r(c)=r_1(c)$ are two representatives, consider $r(c)-r_1(c)$ as a polynomial function of $c$ which is equal to zero and has degree strictly less than the degree of $p$. Use this to conclude on uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a root $c$ of $p(x)$ and show that the homomorphism $F[x]\rightarrow F, \ q\mapsto q(c)$ has kernel $<p(x)>$. Then use the fundamental homomorphism theorem  to obtain the desired isomorphism.

If you have an element $y\in F(c)$ the isomorphism above gives a corresponding polynomial $q$ with $q(c)=y$. But you can choose a representant of $q$ with degree lower than $n$ (polynom division). This is unique since we had an isomorphism and you can only have one representant of degree lower than $n$ since $p$ had degree $n$.